# SQL for following scenario

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, plsql

I have following two tables in the database. One table is person table and other table is Entry table, entry table records the persons entrance to a department

Person Table

```
    Person                  
Person_ID   Person_NIC  Person_Name Person_Last_Name    Person_Age  State
1           121212          ABC         BCD              12         ACTIVE
2           212121          ABB         BBB              13         NONACTIVE
3           111111          BBB         CCC              14         ACTIVE
```

Entry Table

```
ENTRY           
Entry_ID  Person_ID Entry_Escort    Entry_Date  
1         1           David         20121210    
2         1           David         20130110    
3         1           David         20130111    
4         1           David         20130112    
5         1           David     20130113    
6         2           David     20121210    
7         2           David     20130110    
8         2           David     20130111    
9         2           David     20130112    
10        2           David     20130113
```

I have to write sql for following scenario. I need to find Last Entry date for persons how are non active in the database for the month of January. could anybody help me with query. thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: entry table structure is missing in the question ..

Comment: I am trying to added, but stackoverflow is not showing the images

Comment: how in entry related to person? do you have a `person_id` in that table? or `entry_id` maps to `person_nic`?

Comment: Why not show us the create/insert in sql fiddle with some sample data :) It's best you indicate your expected results based on the sample data.

Comment: You are stil missing some date in the entry table.. no relationshp between entry and person...

Comment: I have updated the table, sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as as easy as this:

```
SELECT p.Person_ID, MAX(e.Entry_Date) as MaxEntryDate
FROM 
 Person p 
 INNER JOIN Entry e
   ON p.Person_NIC = e.EntryID
WHERE p.State = 'NONACTIVE'
   AND Entry_Date  BETWEEN 20130101 AND 20130131
GROUP BY p.Person_ID
```

Comment: I need to find Last entry for Non active person in the month of January

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

```
Select 
p.*,
MAX(Entry_Date) 
from 
persons p
inner join entry ep on (p.Person_NIC=ep.Entry_ID)

where State='NONACTIVE'
GROUP BY ep.Entry_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

this should do what you need:

```
select p.person_id, p.person_nic, p.Person_Name, p.Person_Last_Name,
       max(e.entry_date) max_entry_date
 from person p
      inner join entry e
              on e.entry_id = p.person_nic
where p.state = 'NONACTIVE'
group by p.person_id, p.person_nic, p.Person_Name, p.Person_Last_Name
```

p.s. storing AGE in a database table is not good, as you'll have to constantly keep it up to date. it's better to store date of birth and compute age on the fly (or in a view/virtual column)

Answer (score 1):

Try this out please: updated as you need month of january...

### [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87409/1)

```
   Select p.person_id, p.person_nic,
   p.Person_Name,
   p.Person_Last_Name,max(e.entry_date )
   from person p
   inner join entry e 
   on (p.Person_id = e.person_id)
   where p.State='NONACTIVE'
   and month(e.entry_date) = 1
   GROUP BY p.person_nic, e.Entry_ID
   ;

| PERSON_ID | PERSON_NIC | PERSON_NAME | PERSON_LAST_NAME |MAX(E.ENTRY_DATE ) |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         2 |     212121 |         ABB |              BBB | January, 13 2013 |
```

Comment: @kltis check on the demo, I changed some sample data to have `february` as well to trigger the condition you latter mentioned. if you use `month()` then it's more dynamic than adding up any static dates into the query ;)

Comment: @FlorinGhita does none-active define anywhere when uesr started being non-active?

Comment: could you tell me why do you put p.person_nic and e.entry_id in the GROUP BY section

Comment: @Kltis you don't infact need the entry_id in your case but what if the person has entered on the same twice, means he will have two entry ids, then max date is the same but it has two entry ids... unless it will not show it..